# ngrok with docker & nginx. failed to complete tunnel connection

Tags: docker, nginx, ngrok

So if I run ngrok outside of docker, the tunnel connects fine. However when I add it to my docker-compose up i get

`failed to complete tunnel connection`

Here is my docker-compose:

```
services:
  local.box:
    image: nginx:1.21
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/app

ngrok:
    image: ngrok/ngrok:alpine
    depends_on:
      - local.box
    environment:
      - NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=<my_token>
    command: "http local.box:8888"
    volumes:
      - .:/app

networks:
  default:
    name: dev-dev
    external: true
```

I have tried host header rewrites, as well as editing my nginx.conf to not use default server.
The nginx stuff starts up just fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this command to image ngrox:

```
services:
  local.box:
    image: nginx:1.21
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  ngrok:
    image: ngrok:alpine
    depends_on:
      - local.box
    environment:
      - NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=<my_token>
    command: "http local.box:8888"
    volumes:
      - .:/app

networks:
  default:
    name: dev-dev
    external: true
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, however: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ngrok, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

That image does not exist. I double checked within hub.docker.com as well